# Facebook messenger chatbot

Tags: chatbot, facebook-messenger

I've attempted to build a **facebook chatbot**.
I have a bunch of "postback" buttons here:
[image]

when I clicked one of these buttons, I want all buttons will disappear. Like this. (This is **ebay shopbot** )
[image]

Question: How to make these buttons disappear same as they did ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called [Quick Replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies) and tapping them should make them disappear just like the documentation says:

> When a quick reply is tapped, the buttons are dismissed, and the title
>   of the tapped button is posted to the conversation as a message.